Pandas pct_change but loop back to start
I'm looking at how to use the pandas pct_change() function, but I need the values 'wrap around', so the last and first values create a percent change value in position 0 rather than NaN.
For example:
df = pd.DataFrame({'Month':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
                   'Value':[1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.75, 0.75, 0.8, 0.7, 0.65, 0.7, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9]})

    Month  Value
0       1   1.00
1       2   0.90
2       3   0.80
3       4   0.75
4       5   0.75
5       6   0.80
6       7   0.70
7       8   0.65
8       9   0.70
9      10   0.80
10     11   0.85
11     12   0.90

Using pct_change() + 1 gives:
df['percent change'] = df['Value'].pct_change() + 1
    Month  Value  percent change
0       1   1.00             NaN
1       2   0.90        0.900000
2       3   0.80        0.888889
3       4   0.75        0.937500
4       5   0.75        1.000000
5       6   0.80        1.066667
6       7   0.70        0.875000
7       8   0.65        0.928571
8       9   0.70        1.076923
9      10   0.80        1.142857
10     11   0.85        1.062500
11     12   0.90        1.058824

However I also need to know the % change between December (moth=12) and January (month=1), so the NaN should be 1.111111.  I hope to eventually do this to several groups within a group by, so muddling about filling in the Nan with one value over the other, or manually calculating all the percentages seems a long winded way to do it.  Is there a simpler way to achieve this?

Just use numpy.roll that is designed for this specific purpose:
import numpy as np

df['percent change'] = df['Value'].div(np.roll(df['Value'], 1))

Output:
    Month  Value  percent change
0       1   1.00        1.111111
1       2   0.90        0.900000
2       3   0.80        0.888889
3       4   0.75        0.937500
4       5   0.75        1.000000
5       6   0.80        1.066667
6       7   0.70        0.875000
7       8   0.65        0.928571
8       9   0.70        1.076923
9      10   0.80        1.142857
10     11   0.85        1.062500
11     12   0.90        1.058824

If you need to perform this per group, combine it with groupby.transform:
import numpy as np

df['percent change'] = df['Value'].div(df.groupby('Group')['Value'].transform(lambda x: np.roll(x, 1)))

Output:
    Month  Value  Group  percent change
0       1   1.00      1        1.111111
1       2   0.90      1        0.900000
2       3   0.80      1        0.888889
3       4   0.75      1        0.937500
4       5   0.75      1        1.000000
5       6   0.80      1        1.066667
6       7   0.70      1        0.875000
7       8   0.65      1        0.928571
8       9   0.70      1        1.076923
9      10   0.80      1        1.142857
10     11   0.85      1        1.062500
11     12   0.90      1        1.058824
12      1   1.00      2        1.111111
13      2   0.90      2        0.900000
14      3   0.80      2        0.888889
15      4   0.75      2        0.937500
16      5   0.75      2        1.000000
17      6   0.80      2        1.066667
18      7   0.70      2        0.875000
19      8   0.65      2        0.928571
20      9   0.70      2        1.076923
21     10   0.80      2        1.142857
22     11   0.85      2        1.062500
23     12   0.90      2        1.058824


tldr;
df['Value'].pct_change(fill_value=df['Value'].iloc[-1]) + 1


Explanation
pandas Series.pct_change is a thin wrapper on top of performing
Series / Series.shift(...). As it turns out Series.pct_change forwards
extraneous keyword arguments along to Series.shift(...) and this method takes
a fill_value keyword argument to fill in NaN values that result from the shift
operation. The percent change value is then calculated after the .shift
With the above in mind, we can simply specify Series.pct_shift(..., fill_value={last row of Series})
from numpy import roll
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Month':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
    'Value':[1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.75, 0.75, 0.8, 0.7, 0.65, 0.7, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9]
})

df['percent change'] = ( # fill_value = the last number in the 'Value' column
    df['Value'].pct_change(fill_value=df['Value'].iloc[-1]) + 1
)

print(df)
#     Month  Value  percent change
# 0       1   1.00        1.111111
# 1       2   0.90        0.900000
# 2       3   0.80        0.888889
# 3       4   0.75        0.937500
# 4       5   0.75        1.000000
# 5       6   0.80        1.066667
# 6       7   0.70        0.875000
# 7       8   0.65        0.928571
# 8       9   0.70        1.076923
# 9      10   0.80        1.142857
# 10     11   0.85        1.062500
# 11     12   0.90        1.058824


To achieve the desired "wrap-around" behavior using pct_change() in Pandas, you can modify the DataFrame by temporarily shifting the values and then filling the NaN in the first position with the percentage change between the last and the first values.
Here's the code.
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Month': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
    'Value': [1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.75, 0.75, 0.8, 0.7, 0.65, 0.7, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9]
})

df['percent change'] = df['Value'].pct_change() + 1

# Manually fill the first NaN with the change from the last to the first value
df.at[0, 'percent change'] = (df['Value'].iloc[0] / df['Value'].iloc[-1])

print(df)

This can be applied to groupby() too.
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Group': ['A'] * 12 + ['B'] * 12,
    'Month': list(range(1, 13)) * 2,
    'Value': [1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.75, 0.75, 0.8, 0.7, 0.65, 0.7, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9,
              2, 1.8, 1.7, 1.65, 1.65, 1.7, 1.5, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.65, 1.7]
})

def calculate_pct_change(group_df):
    group_df['percent_change'] = group_df['Value'].pct_change() + 1
    group_df.at[group_df.index[0], 'percent_change'] = (group_df['Value'].iloc[0] / group_df['Value'].iloc[-1])

    return group_df

df_grouped = df.groupby('Group').apply(calculate_pct_change).reset_index(drop=True)

print(df_grouped)

I hope this will help you a little.
